# What happens if $|f|$ is constant in the boundary of the image

Tags: complex-analysis

Let D be a domain and let $f$ be analytic on $D$ and continuous on $\overline{D}$. Suppose $|f|$ is constant on $\overline{D}-D$. So from this can we say that $f$ is constant in $D$? I suppose $f$ is constant but then again I do not know how to prove this. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

EDIT: D here is a bounded domain and f is not 0 anywhere in the domain

Comment: Counterexample: $f(z) = z$, $D = \{z: |z| < 1\}$

Comment: Petite's example isn't the only one either, any monomial and any disk centered at the origin will do the job. $\exp$ on the left or right half plane is a somewhat more exotic example.

Comment: @PetiteEtincelle I see that my question has a small flaw. What if cannot be 0 anywhere?

Comment: @Heisenberg In that case my example with $\exp$ comes into play. (My example doesn't work on any bounded domain, however.)

Comment: @Ian How does exp work?

Comment: $|\exp(z)|$ is constant on any vertical line. The left or right half planes have a vertical line as their boundary.

Comment: @Ian Check out my edit hope atleast that would fix it

Comment: @PetiteEtincelle Please check out my edit to the question sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @Heisenberg Half planes aren't bounded domains, but they have a boundary, namely a line.

Comment: @Ian then again does $\overline{D}$ make sense when D is not bounded?

Comment: @Heisenberg Yes, any set has a closure. For an open half plane, say $\{ z : Re(z) > 0 \}$ the closure is the closed half plane $\{ z : Re(z) \geq 0 \}$. But as the answer here shows, on a bounded domain everything works out.

Comment: @Ian But then should't the closure be a closed set?

Comment: @Heisenberg Sure, the closed half plane $\{ z : Re(z) \geq 0 \}$ is a closed set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $D$ is a bounded domain and $f$ is not zero anywhere in the domain, then $|f|$ is constant on $\bar{D} - D$ implies $f$ is a constant:

Suppose $f$ is not a constant and $|f(z)| = C$ on $\bar{D} - D$, by [maximal modulus principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle), we know that for all $z \in D$, $|f(z)| < C$. Because $|f(z)|$ is a continuous function on the bounded $\bar{D}$, then it reached its maximal value on some point in $\bar{D}$. If the maximal value is reached inside $D$, then it's against maximal modulus principle since $f$ is not a constant.

Similarly, we have $\frac{1}{f}$ is not a constant and $\left|\dfrac{1}{f(z)}\right| = \dfrac{1}{C}$ on $\bar{D} - D$, by maximal modulus principle, we know that for all $z \in D$, $\left|\dfrac{1}{f(z)}\right| < \dfrac{1}{C}$.

Then we get a contradiction since we can't have  $|f(z)| < C$ and $\left|\dfrac{1}{f(z)}\right| < \dfrac{1}{C}$ at the same time

Comment: If $f$ vanishes somewhere, then my first comment under the question shows $f$ needs not to be a constant